# Simple date function not working in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
<?php

$year = '2017';
$week = '2';
echo date( "F jS", strtotime($year."W".$week."0"));                         
?>
```

I didn't get the result I expected; I want `Sun 8th`, but I get `May 15th`.

What did I get wrong?

Comment: You are gettings the first Day of Calendarweek 20 in 2017 which is May 15th. You want what Sunday 8th of what Month exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this,

```
$year = "2017"; 
$week = "02"; // Week number must be two digit
$date1 = date( "l, M jS, Y", strtotime($year."W".$week."0") ); // First day of week    
echo $date1;
```

output

```
Sunday, Jan 8th, 2017
```

https://3v4l.org/HbKPU

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Its works fine. Week number must be two digit(02). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the first day of the second week correct? Thats day number 8:

```
echo date( "D jS", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2017));
```